# How to extend the CellSignalStrength class when it doesn't have a constructor?

Tags: java, android, signal-strength

There is a class called `CellSignalStrength` that does not have a default constructor.

To be able to use `SignalStrength`, I have to make a class that extracts it, but I can't because when I try to do that, it prints out the error:

> No default contstructor available for `SignalStrength`.

[image]

Also, there is another class called `CellSignalStrengthGsm`(same problem), but that class extends `SignalStrength` class, but how?

---

I've done some research on this, and i couldn't find anything, but [this guide](http://www.firstdroid.com/2010/05/12/get-provider-gsm-signal-strength/) is only offering the signal strength of neighboring cell-sites to me, none of them is the one providing me with the signal. That solution is offering no actual signal strength.

Why doesn't the Android documentation have at least one example for how to use the class?

I really need help on this, I'm stuck :/

Comment: You cannot instantiate an abstract class but you can extend it.

Comment: no, I can't because of the problem i mentioned above.

LOOK: http://i.imgur.com/W0udYPF.png?1

Comment: Did you try adding a constructor to `MyClass` while extending `CellSignalStrength`?

Comment: @JonnyHenly yeah, i've tried that every which way.

MyClass(){}  , still gives me the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only reason I can think of why you can't extend the `CellSignalStrength` class is because its constructor is `protected CellSignalStrength()`. Meaning only other classes in the same package may extend it.

The Android developers probably had good reason to do so. My suggestion would be to rethink what you're trying to do and figure out another solution. Perhaps using an instance of one of the classes that sub-classes `CellSignalStrength`:

```
Note: These classes are all final, so don't try to extend them.

CellSignalStrengthCdma
CellSignalStrengthGsm
CellSignalStrengthLte
CellSignalStrengthWcdma
```

Comment: This might be wrong however, @PM77-1 had another answer that might be right.

Comment: Seems to me that it's a dead end. Why would they not allow developers to know the signal strength ?

Comment: I think they want you to use the final sub-classes to get the signal strength, because maybe pinging a cell tower is costly on power and they don't want a developer writing code that might have adverse effects that eat away at a phone's battery.

Comment: I guess you're right. Thanks for the answer and your time :)